# How can I select exact color in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector

I made this design in photoshop so basically its on rasterize format, A month later my client want it again but this time it has to be on vector format because it will be print on various colored shirts.
what I did was open it on illustrator and used image trace with high fidelity and expand it, Now what I want is to remove the specific color, black on background so the tree will not be filled. If I use the magic wand it will select the other similar black color.

I love to hear tips and advises too, Is there any better method to do it?

**Rasterized design**
[image: rasterized design]

Answer (score 4):

You can also remove the black color in Illustrator itself. Once you have traced and expanded the image, you need to:

- ungroup the image (Command + Shift + G)
- select any one part of the image that contains the color you want to remove (black in this case) with the Direct Selection Tool (A)
- go to the Select menu > Same > Fill Color

All components that contain black as a fill color will get selected and you can then delete them or fill them with a different color etc. There are other options too with in the Select > Same menu that are useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the magic wand (<kbd>Y</kbd>) to select objects of similar, or even exactly the same, fill or stroke colour. <kbd>double-click</kbd> the tool in the toolbox to set the `Tolerance` to 1, meaning it will only select shapes of exactly the same colour.

Be warned that, depending on your tracing setting, this may leave some not-entirely-black objects behind, you might need to remove those as well.